# Class "App\Models\User" not found in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, model, controller, codeigniter-4

I'm new to CodeIgniter 4 but I have previously used Laravel - so I do know what I'm doing for the most part. I'm trying to build a simple CRUD app on CI4 and in my UserController, it keeps saying that App\Models\User is not found. And as a result - anything I get from the model class, is NULL.

Here's my Model & Controller code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email'];

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->findAll();
    }
}
```

UserController.php:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $model = model(User::class);

        $data['users'] = $model->getUsers();

        return view('user_view', $data);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('add_user');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $model = model(User::class);

        $data = [
            'name' => $this->request->getVar('name'),
            'email' => $this->request->getVar('email')
        ];

        $model->insert($data);
        return $this->response->redirect(site_url('users-list'));
    }
}
```

The error is in the index() method. If I use the $model = model() approach - I get "getUsers() is NULL" error. If I use the $model = new User(); approach - I simply get "Model not Found". And as you can see - I already have included the App\Models\User in the header.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you use the full path to the model instead?

Comment: Check that your Config/Autoload.php is correct and also Config/Paths.php